# Azure DevOps Exception: LinkedAuthorizationFailed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have developed a release pipeline for Azure data Factory which includes blob trigger. The deployment succeeds with exception: LinkedAuthorizationFailed, which results in triggered not being created. Everything else including pipeline and data sets are deployed.Following is the exception I get..

[image]

Not sure what is the cause? Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message, your service principal does not have the permission `Microsoft.EventGrid/EventSubscriptions/Write` on your storage account.

To fix the issue, follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the azure portal -> `Enterprise applications`-> specify the `Application Type` with `All Applications`-> search for the `Client ID` in the error message(the first GUID in `message`), copy the `Name`.

[image]

2.Navigate to the storage account mentioned in the error message ->  `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> search for the `Name` copied in step 1 and add it as a `Contributor` role, then the error should be fixed.

[image]