# Synapse Pipeline Storage Trigger - client does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/write'

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse, azure-eventgrid, azure-triggers

I am trying to create event triggers for synapse pipelines, specifically for when a blob is created. When I create one and publish, I get the following error message:

> The client '...guid...' with object id '...guid...' does not have
> authorization to perform action
> 'Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/write' over scope
> '/subscriptions/...guid.../resourceGroups/...subscription name.../providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/...storage acc name.../providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/...guid...'
> or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
> refresh your credentials.

Following other similar questions asked on this, I have the following permissions:

For synapse workspace:

- Contributor
- EventGrid Contributor

For storage account:

- Contributor
- EventGrid Contributor
- Storage Account Contributor

The synapse workspace was also given the following permissions in the storage account:

- Contributor
- Storage Blob Data Contributor
- Storage Account Contributor

The synapse workspace and I are also granted access in the synapse studios access control.

From what I have read online, I have all the necessary permissions, but I am still getting the error after many days of trying. This is the only permission error I am facing, I am able to connect to storage / databases / key vault / logic apps / etc without any issues. It's only triggers I can't create.

Please let me know if anyone has a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Search client GUID from error in **Enterprise Applications** of your Azure AD tenant by selecting *All applications* and find service principal name. After getting name, assign `Contributor` role to that service principal under your storage account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error usually occurs if the service principal does not have required **roles** or **permissions** like `Microsoft.EventGrid/EventSubscriptions/Write` to perform the operation.

To **resolve** the error, you can follow below steps by assigning proper role to service principal:

Initially, find service principal name by searching **client guid** from error in Enterprise Applications like this:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications -> Set filter to All Applications -> Enter client GUID from error in Search -> Copy Name*

[image]

Now assign **Contributor** role to above service principal under your storage account like below:

[image]

If you prefer to restrict permissions to least privileges, you can assign **EventGrid EventSubscription Contributor** or **EventGrid Contributor** role to the service principal.

Make sure to register below **resource providers** under your subscription like this:

**`Microsoft.EventGrid`**:

[image]

**`Microsoft.DataFactory`**:

[image]

I created one **event trigger** in Synapse pipeline based on blob creation like below:

[image]

To **confirm** that, I uploaded blobs to storage container like below:

[image]

Whenever I uploaded blobs to storage container, it **triggered** events successfully in Synapse pipeline like below:

[image]

**References:**

[Failed to Subscribe / Failed to Activate Storage Event Trigger in Azure Synapse Analytics by **Cathrine Wilhelmsen**](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/failed-subscribe-failed-activate-storage-event-trigger-after-publishing-azure-synapse-analytics/)

[Azure DevOps Exception: LinkedAuthorizationFailed - Stack Overflow by **Joy Wang**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60667396/azure-devops-exception-linkedauthorizationfailed)